# How to `scp` directory preserving structure but only pick certain files?

Tags: bash, scp

I need to secure copy (scp) to remotely copy a directory with its sub structure preserved from the UNIX command line. The sub directories have identically named files that I WANT and bunch of other stuff that I don't. Here is how the structure looks like.

```
directorytocopy
  subdir1
    1.wanted
    2.wanted
    ...
    1.unwanted
    2.notwanted
  subdir2
    1.wanted
    2.wanted
    ...
    1.unwanted
    2.notwanted
  ..
```

I just want the `.wanted` files preserving the directory structure. I realize that it is possible to write a shell (I am using bash) script to do this. Is it possible to do this in a less brute force way? I cannot copy the whole thing and delete the unwanted files because I do not have enough space.

Comment: Use `rsync` with an exclude list instead.

Comment: rsync seems to work! I haven't tried the options in the answers below though. I am confused as to how  to mark rsync as the accepted answer. @AdrianFrühwirth

Comment: Just post what you ended up using and accept your own answer, there's nothing wrong with doing so :-) @HanSolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` with and `-exclude/include` list follwing @Adrian Frühwirth's suggestion would be a to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Adrian has the best idea to use `rsync`. You can also use `tar` to bundle the wanted files:

```
cd directorytocopy
shopt -s nullglob globstar
tar -cf - **/*.wanted | ssh destination 'cd dirToPaste && tar -xvf -'
```

Here, using tar's `-f` option with the filename `-` to use stdin/stdout as the archive file.

This is untested, and may fail because the archive may not contain the actual subdirectories that hold the "wanted" files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU `tar` on the source machine, and assuming that filenames of the wanted files won't contain newlines and they are short enough to fit the `tar` headers:

```
find /some/directory -type f -name '*.wanted' | \
    tar cf - --files-from - | \
    ssh user@host 'cd /some/other/dir && tar xvpf -'
```